# How do I inject $rootScope into an AngularJS unit test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dependency-injection, angularjs, jasmine

Suppose I have a service that depends on a value in $rootScope, as with the following (trivial) service:

```
angular.module('myServices', [])
.factory('rootValGetterService', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        getVal: function () {
            return $rootScope.specialValue;
        }
    };
});
```

If I want to unit test this by putting a value in $rootScope, what is the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 22):

```
...
var $rootScope;
beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_) {
  $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
}));
...
```

Comment: Doesn't this give you the same scope for every test? How do you pass a fresh new scope to the service?

Comment: Hi Tamlyn, in what way is your root scope no longer fresh? I believe I've only ever used it to broadcast events.

Comment: The underscores are needed because there is otherwise a naming conflict between the `$rootScope` in the closure and `$rootScope` argument.

Comment: @Tamlyn this one gives a new isolated $rootScope to each test.
If anyone doesn't like the underscore convention can write it like this 
`beforeEach(inject($injector => {
  $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
}))`

Answer (score 6):

By using provide(), you can inject a new $rootScope:

```
describe('in rootValGetter', inject(function ($rootScope) {
    var scope;
    var testRootValGetter;

    beforeEach(function () {

        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        module(function ($provide) {
            $provide.value('$rootScope', scope);
        });

        inject(function ($injector) {
            testRootValGetterService = $injector.get('rootValGetterService');
        });
    });

    it('getVal returns the value from $rootScope', function() {
        var value = 12345;

        scope.specialValue = value;

        expect(testRootValGetterService.getVal()).toBe(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: This pattern is not working for me. Angular keeps throwing this error: "Error: Injector already created, can not register a module!"

Comment: Why do you need to use `scope = $rootScope.$new();`, instead of using `$rootScope` directly?

Comment: To have a clean $rootScope, you could try to inject it from beforeEach: `beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope) {`

Comment: Does anyone know why this happens if you put it on the top-level describe? Took awhile working backwards to figure out where I was getting this error from.

Answer (score 3):

Include `angular-mocks.js`, then use [`angular.mock.inject`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject):

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a new scope as you would if you were injecting `$scope` you can mock the properties you need directly into `$rootScope`.

Then `$rootScope` will be injected with those properties available in the code you are testing.

At least this is the way I solved the same problem.

The following code should work in your example.

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.specialValue = 'whatever';
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to give a more detailed answer including the test case:

...

```
var $rootScope;
beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_) {
  $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
}));
```

...

```
  it('getVal returns the value from $rootScope', function() {
        var value = 12345;
        $rootScope.specialValue = value;
        expect(testRootValGetterService.getVal()).toBe(value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

```
it('some kind of wacky test', function($rootScope, Translate){
    $rootScope.lang = 'en';
    expect(Translate('overview').toBe('Overview');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps others as this was the solution to a similar problem.

```
var rootValGetterService;

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope,$injector) {
    $rootScope.specialValue = "test";
    rootValGetterService= $injector.get('rootValGetterService');
}));

it("Should have a service", function () {
    expect(rootValGetterService).toBeDefined();
});
```