# angularjs: how to mock $rootScope in unit test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, mocking

I have a unit test that looks like this

```
describe('Interceptor: myInterceptor', inject(function($rootScope){
    var rootScope, routeParams = { id: null };

    beforeEach(module('MyApp', function ($provide) {
        $provide.factory('$routeParams', function () {   // mock $routeParams
            return routeParams;
        });

        rootScope = $rootScope.$new();
        $provide.value('$rootScope', rootScope);         // mock $rootScope

    }));
    ....
}));
```

However when I do "inject(function($rootScope){ .." as I have shown above, I get the following error (using Karma and PhantomJS):

```
PhantomJS 1.9.2 (Mac OS X) Interceptor: myInterceptor encountered a declaration exception FAILED
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'currentSpec.$modules')
    at workFn (/dev/myapp/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2072)
    at /dev/myapp/test/spec/interceptors/my-interceptor.js:67
    ....
```

Comment: My question is potentially related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416006/how-do-i-inject-rootscope-into-an-angularjs-unit-test

Answer (score 5):

I don't think injection works when calling `describe`. I had the same error which I solved by moving the injection from my `describe` call to a `beforeEach` call:

```
var rootScope;
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope) {
    rootScope = $rootScope.$new();
}));
```

You can have multiple `beforeEach`, so just add this one above your existing `beforeEach`.

Comment: but from some reason you cannot do: beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $provide) { ... }