# Why does the $rootScope state persist between my tests?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I've set up a test suite for testing the behaviour of a controller in my app. The controller has a function which puts attributes on the $rootScope. My problem is that these attributes persist after the test has run, and their presence causes unwanted behaviour in other test cases.
This happens despite the fact that I try recreating the same settings for every test with detailed `beforeEach` blocks - in fact the "corrupted" state even persists in all the future test runs on the same Karma server! (stopping and restarting the server of course clears it)

Here's some of my code to put things into context. First I do a simple test to see if the function (that'll be modifying the rootScope later) gets defined at all:

```
describe('testing my controller', function () {

var scope;

beforeEach(function(){
    angular.mock.module('mainApp');
});

beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    //if I observe the contents of the $rootScope here, the effects of previous runs
    //    of tests cases after this one can be seen on it!
    scope = {};
    $controller('myCtrl', {$scope: scope});
}));

it('should define the function', function () {
    expect(typeof scope.myFunc).toBe('function');
});
```

Then later in the same file, but a different `describe` block, I have more tests, with their own seperate `beforeEach` blocks, which I would expect to re-set the environment for them:

```
    beforeEach(function(){
    angular.mock.module('mainApp');
    //(...)
    //here I create an other module for some mocked services
    angular.mock.module('myMockModule');
```

And then I do the same inject block as above to instantiate the controller. In the test cases of this latter block, I call the `myFunc` function on the controller, which sets the variables on the rootScope, simply like this:

```
$rootScope.variable = "asdfg";
```

(at the controller's definition, $rootScope is passed to it as a parameter.) After this test has run, `$rootScope.variable` stays defined, both in the following tests, and all the tests in the subsequent test runs, as long as the karma server is not restarted.

I've tried changing the way I instantiate the controller, passing it $rootScope just like I pass that other scope (both with and without making sure there's no name resolution clashes by wrapping $rootScope in underscores), tried both passing $rootScope as a parameter in that inject call and not, but I couldn't get rid of this behaviour.

What's happening here? Why is the rootScope object persisting? What is the proper way of creating a mocked rootScope in the unit tests, and making sure all tests can start from the same clean state?

Comment: Did you check the answers to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416006/how-do-i-inject-rootscope-into-an-angularjs-unit-test

Comment: Simon, thanks for your answer! That pattern does not work for me - and looking at the comments there, not for others either. You can't call the module function after calling inject (this results in an "Injector already created, can not register a module!" error) - and I'm not sure how can one get a reference to $rootScope without inject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would need to see your test file entirely because I can't follow your question at all. On the one hand, you shouldn't load modules in that way, load them all at the beginning or you will get that `injector already created` which means that you can't use `inject()` and after that `module()`.

On the other hand, `$rootScope` is never going to carry values between tests, you did something wrong but with the actual code, I can't see it.

Check this demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/siHHqg4HLkwpZUyby83r?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I actually solved the issue in the last few days, my problem was indeed in code not posted here: I didn't mock all the services used by my controller properly, and one of them stored some values in external storage, which gave the illusion of the rootScope state persisting.  

    
I'll accept this as the correct answer, because your statement is true, and it was sort of the solution to my problem too: the $rootScope is **not** carrying value between tests.

Comment: btw, the module loading was correct, I'm not calling module after inject anywhere.